# Could not autowire. No beans found for GraphRepo. Testing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a normal java web application with main and test. In main I have models, repository and service. The main works fine. I can autowire the repository in service. In test, when I try to autowire the repository, it gives the error from the title. Could not autowire. No beans found for GraphRepo. right where I define the rentedRepo. I don't understand what the problem is

RepoTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ITConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@DatabaseSetup("/META-INF/dbtest/db-data.xml")
public class RentedRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private GraphRepo rentedRepo;
}
```

ITConfig code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "ro.ubb.stcatalog.core",
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = {JPAConfig.class}, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE)})
@Import({JPAConfigIT.class})
@PropertySources({@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db-h2.properties")})
public class ITConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

JPAConfig code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("ro.ubb.stcatalog.core.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfigIT {

    //    @Value("${db.jdbcURL}")
    private String jdbcURL = "";

    //    @Value("${db.user}")
    private String user = "postgres";

    //    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password = "";

    //    @Value("${db.generateDDL}")
    private Boolean generateDDL = true;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ro.ubb.stcatalog.core.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
//        factory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Why isn't the test Autowire not working? I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the repository because I tried autowiring a simple repository which implements the JPA one too and I have the same error. If necessary I can post more.

I tried adding the @Repository annotation to the GraphRepo even though it also implements the JPA one but no change at all

EDIT: Alright. I ran the test with the error on it and apparently, my test directory doesn't see the Maven imports? I get a lot of errors.
[image]

So it wont see my dependencies. Here I have the parent dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.ubb.stcatalog</groupId>
    <artifactId>stcatalog-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>stcatalog-core</module>
        <module>stcatalog-web</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <spring-test-dbunit.version>1.1.0</spring-test-dbunit.version>

        <!-- DB -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <HikariCP-java6.version>2.2.5</HikariCP-java6.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.182</h2.version>

        <!-- Web -->
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>

        <!-- Parsers -->
        <jackson.version>2.3.3</jackson.version>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <commons-lang.version>3.3.2</commons-lang.version>

        <!-- Utilities -->
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.8</lombok.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.5</log4j.version>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <hamcrest-all.version>1.3</hamcrest-all.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.5.2</dbunit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- ====== -->
            <!-- Spring -->
            <!-- ====== -->
            <!-- Spring Framework -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-test-dbunit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Data -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring MVC -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- DATABASE & TRANSACTION MANAGER RELATED -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
                <version>${HikariCP-java6.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- PostgreSQL -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- H2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Parsers -->
            <!-- JSON -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- ============== -->
            <!-- Apache Commons -->
            <!-- ============== -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ========= -->
            <!-- Utilities -->
            <!-- ========= -->
            <!-- GUAVA -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- Logging -->
            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- SLF4J -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ======= -->
            <!-- Testing -->
            <!-- ======= -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
                <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- ====== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Parsers -->
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <!-- ============== -->
        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <!-- ============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Testing -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the child pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>stcatalog-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>ro.ubb.stcatalog</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>stcatalog-core</name>

    <artifactId>stcatalog-core</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DATABASE & TRANSACTION RELATED -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ========= -->
        <!-- Utilities -->
        <!-- ========= -->
        <!-- GUAVA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Testing -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Is there any error in them?

EDIT: Restarting the IDE solved the Autowire problem but the package errors are still there

Is there anything I could try on the pom to force it to be seen?

Comment: Maybe dependency conflicts?  Your errors are coming from an IDE, did you use your pom to import the project?  Is the IDE even aware of the pom?  What happens when you use the Maven command line tool to run your tests?

Comment: The IDE sees my imports because when I run the src java code, the application works perfectly. Only the test directory doesn't seem to see my imports. I run the tests by setting test directory as src and just regular run All tests

Comment: The IDE sees your imports, but does it see them because it parses your pom?  I'm trying to determine if your IDE is misconfigured or if there is a problem with your POM.  Use a command line tool to navigate to the root of your project and run `mvn test` and tell us what happens.  Also, what IDE are you using and how did you set up the project.

Comment: Yea the problem was that I set up my tests wrong. They were setted up as source code instead of test source code